# du -sh behaviour in terminal and from an python script?

Tags: python, linux, shell, terminal, du

With reference to [my question at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/507666/email-file-and-folder-list-with-size), I am facing a puzzling situation where using `du -sh /media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*` works as expected from terminal, but using `p=subprocess.Popen(['du', '-sh', '/media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` in a python script shows `error du: cannot access /media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal expands the * for you.
To tell subprocess to do that:

```
p=subprocess.Popen('du -sh /tmp/*', shell=True)
```

Or you could use the glob module to expand the * yourself,
if you needed more control

Answer (score 0):

You should add the parameter `shell=True` to your subprocess.Popen func. So that you can invoke the shell and use environment variables, file globs etc.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['du', '-sh', '/media/ExternalHd/myfolder/*'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

However, you should avoid using `shell=True` because of the security hazards, see the warning in [python subprocess module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module). For a small script like this, maybe it doesn't create a problem, but keep in mind ;)

For further details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488) to another stackoverflow question.